# How can I handle touches outside of the nav drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, touch-event

I have a set of buttons in my *Android* app that change the content of the *Nav Drawer* when selected. Ideally, when the user clicks one of these buttons, the *Nav Drawer* content will change right away.

However, because the *Nav Drawer* captures the touch events first, the first click closes the *Nav Drawer* and the second one changes the content (and reopens the drawer). **Is there a simple way to handle clicks outside of the *Nav Drawer* before the *Nav Drawer* captures them?** I have tried changing the *Z-Order* of my buttons, but this had no effect.

Finally, to add the the complexity of this problem, I only want to allow this behavior for my right-side *Nav-Drawer*. The left-side drawer should always close no matter where outside the drawer the user touches.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine extending the NavigationDrawer class and overriding the onTouch would achieve what you are looking for.